# Athena fails to parse collections with LazySimpleSerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-athena

It appears that AWS Athena fails to correctly load collection fields when using LazySimpleSerDe; setting collection.delim appears to have no effect, e.g. when used thusly:

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = '|',
'field.delim' = '|',
'collection.delim' = ',',
'line.delim' = '\n',
'mapkey.delim' = '@'
)
```

This does appear to be running locally (on a slightly different Hadoop version), but not on EMR.

Is there any way to load collection fields from a TSV file or similar to Athena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the current (September 2017) Hive version of Athena contains a typo in the field name: it's called 'colelction.delim' ([reference](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=264065), [relevant fix](https://github.com/apache/hive/commit/c59a8c6d1cfbb436deeadf842b20c5d212213dd1)).

Until a fix is released, using the typo does work:

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = '|',
'field.delim' = '|',
'colelction.delim' = ',',
'mapkey.delim' = '@'
```

Comment: Very little info on that in the internet, will accept own answer when possible as the issue was solved, however will gladly accept better answers (e.g. with a walkaround which would still work after the typo is fixed, or otherwise)